# Localisation and JSON in Angular

Tags: json, angular, localization

I have a JSON database, sample provided below:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "-Kowtg5yyK-DTIz91cQ8" : {
      "language" : "en",
      "uid" : "kNyDJnktxyakL6owhGd1rruGACb2",
      "userName" : "admin"
    }
  },
  "localisation" : {
    "login" : {
      "en" : "Login",
      "ru" : "Войти",
      "uk" : "Увійти"
    },
    "logout" : {
      "en" : "Logout",
      "ru" : "Выйти",
      "uk" : "Вийти"
    }
  }
}
```

I am writing an Angular4 app. The database is in Firebase. To access it I used angularfire2:

```
export class AppComponent {
  localisation: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  userProfile : FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    userProfile = db.list('/users/')
    this.localisation = db.list('/localisation/');
  }
}
```

1) Is it a good idea to use the localisation like this or is there a better way?

---

2) How can I access only for example login in en? I tried in *.html

```
{{ (localisation | async).login.en }}
```

I only manage to get en by iterating  with *ngFor

```
  <md-list-item *ngFor="let lang of localisation | async">
    {{ lang.en }}
  </md-list-item>
```

but I know that this is very unpractical and especially if I add "if" for every language. Is it another way to applying language settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tried and tested frameworks for doing just this. You could (and probably should) use a library like [ngx-translate](http://www.ngx-translate.com/). They provide a relatively easy way of inserting translations from JSON.

---

Regarding the other questions, if you are going to roll your own translations:

1) Is it a good idea to use the localization like this or is there a better way?

With this approach, you'll have to load in translations from all supported languages in one go. If you just wanted the translations for English, you will still get all the other languages as well. This will also mean that you have to have logic to get the correct language.

A common approch to this is to have translations seperated by language. 
ex -

```
'en': {
    "LOGOUT": "Logout",
    "LOGIN" : "Login",
}
"ru": {
    "LOGOUT": "Выйти"
    "LOGIN": "Войти",
}
```

That way, you'll easily be able to change out the entire object when the language changes.

2) How can I access only for example login in en? I tried in *.html

```
{{ (localisation | async).login.en }}
```

This approach should work, given that you get only the `localisation` objects from the firebase response.

But with this approach for translations, you will have to change the template when the language has changed.